# How do I get my desktop (windows 7) on my DLNA TV?

Tags: tv, upnp, dlna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live screencasting from a Windows PC to a DLNA-enabled TV - possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/337978/live-screencasting-from-a-windows-pc-to-a-dlna-enabled-tv-possible)

It looks like the world+dog is [writing wrappers](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/21-how-to-choose-dlna-media-server-windows-mac-os-x-or-linux) around vlc and ffmpeg to provide a DLNA server, but everything I've looked at can only cope with files stored on the local hard disk. I'd like to project my desktop onto a DLNA TV - but I can't find a method for doing that.

(I'm not bothered about provisioning for a keyboard/mouse at the TV - I just want to use it as a projector)

Any ideas?

TIA