# Live screencasting from a Windows PC to a DLNA-enabled TV - possible?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, screencasts, dlna

We're looking to buy some LCD monitors to be used as dashboard displays in the development offices around here at work. Primarily they will display information from a PC directly connected via HDMI or VGA. However, an awesome use case would be where team members can broadcast a live view of their monitor to the TV for the rest of the room to watch (and maybe listen to).

Would it be possible to do this via DLNA with some sort of executable on the broadcasting machine that spoke as a DLNA server to the DLNA client (the TV)?

Does anyone know of anything similar? Should I avoid DLNA completely and just go low-fi and just get staff to use the connected dashboard machine directly with VNC?

I've found [this script for linux](http://realmike.org/blog/2011/02/09/live-desktop-streaming-via-dlna-on-gnulinux/) but because of how many machines and TVs we're talking about I'd prefer to have something that was simply install and go, rather than have to go through the effort of everything that the script would require to become operational on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question (from 2011), and there's still no reasonable way of doing this. DLNA is not intended for live content mirroring. Its just the wrong tool for the job.

The best way to achieve screen mirroring/extension to televisions in 2016/2017 is to use a Miracast receiver (built-in to most 'smart' TVs these days, or something like the [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/adapters/wireless-display-adapter-2/p3q-00001)) with [Windows 10's 'project to display' functionality](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15053/windows-8-project-wireless-screen-miracast) or use a Google (Chrome)Cast to [mirror Chrome or your desktop](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?hl=en-GB).

Answer (score 0):

To encode a video stream of a user desktop is non trivial.  Then that would have to be put on the DNLA server or each endpoint would have to connect to the desktop which would probably be a pain.
I imagine if you want to coordinate a lot of displays it would be easiest to just throw a raspberry on all the displays and then you can do some scripting to get them all to coordinate.  Work to set up but then much easier to operate.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)